# Hoisted local variable masking global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, emscripten

Came across strange behavior in `node`.  I have an [emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/) compiled program that I would like to use as a library.  `emscripten` use a variable `Module` to control runtime behavior, and generates code like `./lib/g.js` below.  In the browser, `Module` is properly aliased from the global defined in `index.js` to the local `var` in `./lib/g.js`.  However, in `node`, this does not seem to be the case.  The construct: `var Module = Module || {};` wipes out my global `Module`.

`index.js`:

```
global.Module = { name: 'Module' };
var g = require ( './lib/g.js' );
```

`./lib/g.js`:

```
console.log ( 'Module: ', Module );

var Module = Module || {};
```

Output of `node index.js`:

```
Module:  undefined
```

I assume in `g.js`, `Module` is hoisted and dereferenced only in the local scope, masking the global version (in `global.Module`).  Can anyone suggest a work-around?

This problem can be fixed by editing the `emscripten` produced code to use `var Module = global.Module || {}`.  While this is a possible workaround, I would rather not edit the code generated by `emscripten`.

Comment: If there is a `Module` defined at a higher scope, then `var Module = Module || {}` will just create an alias for it in this scope.  Accessing properties on `Module` will work just fine to access the properties of the higher scoped variable.

Comment: @jfriend00: this is the expected behavior, but didn't work that way in the example given.  Works properly in the browser, but not in `node`.  Didn't find variable scoping rules for `node` that covered this case.

Comment: Looks like emscripten does expect its output scripts to be run in the global scope, not in a module scope. You could try global eval, if you don't want to edit the code.

Comment: This looks to me like you have a conflict between a global `Module` that emscripten is using and the global `Module` that node uses.  Perhaps they are both trying to define/use the same or one is redefining and overriding the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at using [rewire](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rewire)

```
var rewire = require("rewire");
var g = rewire("./lib/g");
g.__set__("Module", {name: "Module"});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone suggest a work-around?

Just remove the `var` keyword.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity.  What I am trying to avoid is editing the code generated by `emscripten`.  Changing generated code is not always a good idea.  Will ask the `emscripten` community directly.